# Single dimensional numeric array converted to object array in PHP. How the value of object array can be accessed by its index

Tags: php, arrays, object, variables, array-indexing

Here I have a single dimension numeric array

```
$x = array(1,2,3,4);
```

Below converted to an object array

```
$x = (object) $x;
```

I am not able to access values by its index

```
echo  $x->{'1'} //Tried but not working
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes from the index in the echo statement:

```
$x = array(1,2,3,4);
$x = (object) $x;

echo $x->{1};
```

Returns

> 2

Comment: http://phpfiddle.org/ here i tested your code. Giving me error {E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined property: stdClass::$1 -- at line 5}

Comment: Tested [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4ec1c667337aecbc039b3e743a6da463581f79fe) with PHP 7.2. What version did you use?

Comment: I m using 5.6 php version.

Comment: That is the problem. 5.6 will not use that syntax. What version is on your server?